# Closed form for $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2^n}}-1}{\frac{x}{2^n}}$

Tags: closed-form, infinite-product

I would like to know if there is a closed-form for
\begin{align*}
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2^n}}-1}{\frac{x}{2^n}},
\end{align*}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The closest results I could find in the [literature](https://doi.org/10.3390/sym14071418) were
\begin{align*}
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+e^{\frac{x}{2^n}}}{1+e^{\frac{y}{2^n}}} &= \frac{e^x-1}{x} \frac{y}{e^y-1},\\
  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+e^{-x 2^n}\right) &= \frac{1}{2} (1+\coth(x)).
\end{align*}

The motivation for this problem comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744218). I was interested in calculating the moment-generating function for the random variable $L = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{U_n}{2^n}$, where $U_n$ are iid random variables that follow a uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. After some calculations, I ended up with this infinite product.

Comment: Have you tried plotting points of that infinite product numerically? That might give a rough idea

Comment: @VincentBatens, yes I did! It is close to $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ around $0$, but then it diverges.